# Allow ConfigParser to parse $ as a string if not followed by { during interpolation

Tags: python, configparser

I want to use `ConfigParser` to `interpolate` variables in a `.ini` file in `python` and parse `$` symbols not immediately followed by `{` symbol as strings while still interpolate variables that follow the `${...}` syntax.

Here's a `test.ini` file example:

```
[variables]
; test.ini
example1 = interpolate
example2 = please_${example1}_me
example3 = $please_leave_me_alone
example4 = $foo-${example2}-$bar
```

Parsed with this code:

```
# python 2.7
from backports.configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation
parser = ConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())
parser.read('test.ini')

for section in parser.sections():
    for key in parser[section]:
        print parser[section][key]
```

`example2` would properly interpolate to `please_interpolate_me` but `example3` and `example4` would both raise an `InterpolationSyntaxError` for containing `$` not immediately followed by `{`.

As a patch I could use two parsers with a `try/except` switch to get passed the exception:

```
# python 2.7
from backports.configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation
parser1 = ConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())
parser2 = ConfigParser() # to handle exceptions
parser1.read('test.ini')
parser2.read('test.ini')

for section in parser1.sections():
    for key in parser1[section]:
        try:
            print parser1[section][key] # interpolated
        except:
            print parser2[section][key] # leave as is
```

But this is not ideal as it would not interpolate `example4` to `$foo-please_interpolate_me-$bar`

**QUESTION**

Can ConfigParser be configured to parse `$` symbols not immediately followed by `{` symbols as strings and still interpolate variables that follow the `${...}` syntax? How could I get `example4` to parse as `$foo-please_interpolate_me-$bar`?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest would likely be to subclass [`configparser.ExtendedInterpolation::before_get`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/configparser.py#L453) and special-case the lone `"$"` in it. That is, if `value` is `"$"`, do not call `_interpolate_some(...)` and just return the value.

Note: you will have to [pass the custom interpolation as `interpolation` constructor argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects).

(Disclaimer: did not test.)